# Mixing C-preprocessor and scripting language with highlighting?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

We are using a proprietary tool which uses Tcl and the C preprocessor to create input files.  Is there any way to get the Tcl syntax highlighting to also recognize the `#if`, `#else`, `#endif` macro conditional from the C preprocessor.  The goal would be to be able to quickly jump between the macro blocks with the `%` key.

This kind of works if we set the language to c:

```
:setf c
```

and then placing the mouse of the relevant macro conditional and hitting the `%` key

```
#if sldkfjlkj 
set dog cat
set dog cat
set dog cat
#else
#if 0
set dog cat
#else
set dog cat
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: you could try setting the filetype to "c.tcl" so that both filetype plugins are loaded. That only works however, if the syntax/filetype plugins support it. Or for your case, simply create a file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tcl.vim` and set the `b:match_words` variables like from the ftplugin/c.vim file

Answer (score 1):

Motions between the macro blocks should already be covered by the built-in `%` motion; it expressly handles `#if, #ifdef, #else, #elif, #endif`; cp. `:help %`.

I've extracted the preprocessor-related syntax elements from the built-in C syntax file, and put them into a separate syntax extension script, now published as the [syn-preproc plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5484).

With that, it should be sufficient to

```
:setf tcl.preproc
```

and you enjoy highlighting and folding of `#ifdef` and so on in addition to the normal Tcl highlighting.